# Spring boot job scheduler works fine on local machine but getting error on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, job-scheduling, tomcat9, ftp-server

I am trying to run an application that will list all the file in an FTP server . The programme works fine on local machine but getting error when deploying to AWS.

```
    26-Apr-2021 16:16:17.519 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [DropShippingApplication] appears to have started a thread named [scheduling-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
         java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
         java.base@11.0.9/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
         java.base@11.0.9/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
         java.base@11.0.9/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
         org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:321)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:523)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:847)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:785)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3409)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3339)
         org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:3016)
         com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.copyFileFromFTPtoAWS_v2(Schedular.java:95)
         com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.performDailyTask(Schedular.java:61)
         java.base@11.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         java.base@11.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
         java.base@11.0.9/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
         org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
         org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
         java.base@11.0.9/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        26-Apr-2021 16:16:17.549 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
        26-Apr-2021 16:16:17.590 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
        26-Apr-2021 16:16:20.803 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
                        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1038)
                        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
                        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    2021-04-26 16:16:22
    Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.9+11-LTS mixed mode, sharing):
    
    Threads class SMR info:
    _java_thread_list=0x00007f3444090ab0, length=13, elements={
    0x00007f3474051000, 0x00007f3474053000, 0x00007f3474059000, 0x00007f347405b800,
    0x00007f347405d800, 0x00007f347405f800, 0x00007f34740a3800, 0x00007f34740a7000,
    0x00007f34740ef000, 0x00007f3474114000, 0x00007f3475ab7800, 0x00005618fef93800,
    0x00007f3474016000
    }
    
    "Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=2.80ms elapsed=2265.69s tid=0x00007f3474051000 nid=0x4967 waiting on condition  [0x00007f3479e24000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
            at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
            at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.9/Reference.java:241)
            at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.9/Reference.java:213)
    
    "Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=0.84ms elapsed=2265.69s tid=0x00007f3474053000 nid=0x4968 in Object.wait()  [0x00007f3479d23000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
            at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
            - waiting on <no object reference available>
            at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
            - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000d55c78f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
            at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
            at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@11.0.9/Finalizer.java:170)
    
    "Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.07ms elapsed=2265.69s tid=0x00007f3474059000 nid=0x4969 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    "C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=17943.32ms elapsed=2265.69s tid=0x00007f347405b800 nid=0x496a waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
       No compile task
    
    "C1 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=4378.68ms elapsed=2265.69s tid=0x00007f347405d800 nid=0x496b waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
       No compile task
    
    "Sweeper thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=471.47ms elapsed=2265.68s tid=0x00007f347405f800 nid=0x496c runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    
    "Common-Cleaner" #8 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=3.35ms elapsed=2265.64s tid=0x00007f34740a3800 nid=0x496d in Object.wait()  [0x00007f347981e000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
            at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
            - waiting on <no object reference available>
            at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.9/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
            - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000d55c7f68> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
            at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@11.0.9/CleanerImpl.java:148)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.9/Thread.java:834)
"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.05ms elapsed=2265.62s tid=0x00007f34740a7000 nid=0x496e runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"AsyncFileHandlerWriter-1706234378" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=134.94ms elapsed=2265.56s tid=0x00007f34740ef000 nid=0x4970 waiting on condition  [0x00007f34790c0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d55c82b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.base@11.0.9/LockSupport.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(java.base@11.0.9/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.pollFirst(java.base@11.0.9/LinkedBlockingDeque.java:513)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.poll(java.base@11.0.9/LinkedBlockingDeque.java:675)
        at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$LoggerThread.run(AsyncFileHandler.java:159)

"FileHandlerLogFilesCleaner-1" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=20.71ms elapsed=2265.48s tid=0x00007f3474114000 nid=0x4971 waiting on condition  [0x00007f3478fbf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000d55c84d0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.9/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.9/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@11.0.9/LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.9/Thread.java:834)

"scheduling-1" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=224.68ms elapsed=2243.34s tid=0x00007f3475ab7800 nid=0x4979 runnable  [0x00007f343bcfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:178)
        - locked <0x00000000c64f8f40> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@11.0.9/InputStreamReader.java:185)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(java.base@11.0.9/BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(java.base@11.0.9/BufferedReader.java:182)
        - locked <0x00000000c64f8f40> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
        - locked <0x00000000c64f8f40> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:321)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:523)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:847)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:785)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3409)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3339)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:3016)
        at com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.copyFileFromFTPtoAWS(Schedular.java:108)
        at com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.performDailyTask(Schedular.java:61)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@11.0.9/Executors.java:515)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(java.base@11.0.9/FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.9/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.9/Thread.java:834)
"scheduling-1" #45 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=160.16ms elapsed=435.39s tid=0x00005618fef93800 nid=0x4a6f runnable  [0x00007f34322fc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.9/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@11.0.9/StreamDecoder.java:178)
        - locked <0x00000000c6681ff8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@11.0.9/InputStreamReader.java:185)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(java.base@11.0.9/BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.read(java.base@11.0.9/BufferedReader.java:182)
        - locked <0x00000000c6681ff8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at org.apache.commons.net.io.CRLFLineReader.readLine(CRLFLineReader.java:58)
        - locked <0x00000000c6681ff8> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:321)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:523)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:847)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:785)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3409)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3339)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:3016)
        at com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.copyFileFromFTPtoAWS_v2(Schedular.java:95)
        at com.motionFashion.DropShippingApplication.JobScheduler.Schedular.performDailyTask(Schedular.java:61)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.9/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.9/Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@11.0.9/Executors.java:515)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(java.base@11.0.9/FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.9/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.9/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.9/Thread.java:834)
```

**Function used for Schedular**

```
public void copyFileFromFTPtoAWS_v2(User user ){
    System.out.println("****************--------copyFileFromFTPtoAWS--------****************");
    System.out.println("user  -:"+user.getUsername());
    int port = 21;
    String ftp_server =user.getFtp_server();
    String ftp_username = user.getFtp_username();
    String ftp_password = user.getFtp_password();

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    FTPClientConfig conf = new FTPClientConfig();
    conf.setServerTimeZoneId("UTC");
    ftpClient.configure(conf);

    try {
        ftpClient.connect(ftp_server, port);
        ftpClient.login(ftp_username, ftp_password);

        System.out.println("listFiles--->message");
        FTPFile[] message = ftpClient.listFiles("/message");
        System.out.println("list-message"+message.length);
        System.out.println("listFiles--->order");
        FTPFile[] order = ftpClient.listFiles("/order");
        System.out.println("list-order"+order.length);

        String path = ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
        System.out.println("path :"+path);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

> In the schedular i checked for active user then send the user to the above function to get their file  two folder "message" and "order" inside FTP server.
> But in **FTPFile[] message = ftpClient.listFiles("/message");** line
> I am getting the error .

**performDailyTask function on JobSchedular**

```
 @Autowired
Ftp_File_service ftpFile_service;
@Autowired
storageService storageService;
@Autowired
UserService userService;
@Autowired
OrderService OrderService;
@Autowired
EmailService emailService;

DateFormat dateFormater2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm");
DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm");

FTPClient ftp = null;

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;


//300000    -> 5 min
//600000    -> 10 min
@SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000)//..................................................................UPDATE bestand_komplett
public void performDailyTask(){

System.out.println("**************************performDailyTask**************************");

    List<User> userList = userService.findAllClient();

    if(!userList.isEmpty())
    {
        List<User> newUserList=userService.findAllActiveClient(userList);
        if(!newUserList.isEmpty()){

            for(User user : newUserList)
            {
                copyFileFromFTPtoAWS_v2(user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**new Error**

```
    **************************performDailyTask**************************
time
26/04/2021 20:48:41
****************--------copyFileFromFTPtoAWS--------****************
user  -:mds001
listFiles--->message
list-message0
listFiles--->order
26-Apr-2021 20:51:58.272 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:559)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace/errors as code and not as an image and please properly try to format your code block. There appears to be some part missing.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I have edited the post

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. When the application shuts down you didn't shutdown the threadpool that is executing the FTP connections.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  That is what catalina.out is printing. And there is no other error is mentioned in the log file...!! and except  Jobschedular all other functionalities are working properly.And the Jobschedular is working properly on local environment.Can you give me any suggestion .

Comment: This warning means: _"the application is being stopped, but no one stopped this thread."_. It's not a clean shutdown, but it's not an error. Can you provide more details how do you start those asyncronous tasks? E.g. what is `Schedular`? BTW: you are using camelcase package names. The convention in Java is to use lowercase.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz In my project I need to create a service where the application should check all the user and list their file from FTP server . For that I have used the JobSchudler.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have attached the "performDailyTask" function on JobSchedular .Which perform task every 10 minutes.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I think I found the error . Can you take a look on the post , I you can find the log right below "new Error"

Answer (score 0):

```
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.type(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

This two line after FTP connect solved my problem .Since I am getting no Error except some warning on log file.